# To perform find/count operation on map c++

Tags: dictionary, c++11, vector, stl

I have map data structure `map<string, vector< pair<string, string> >`, where map `key` is of `string` data type and value is `vector<pair<string, string> >`  data type.

if i try to perform `find` or `count` operation using `key` value which is of string data type. I do get compilation issue.

why is it behaving so? i should have able to perform either `find`/`count` operation on map!

basically i have `typedef` the map data structure as below:-

```
typedef pair<string,string> attribute_pair;
typedef vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef map<string,attribute_vector> testAttribute_map;
```

part of the code snippet where trying to perform find operation

```
 testAttribute_map attributes;
 string fileName = "Hello.cpp";
 if(testAttribute_map iter = attributes.find(fileName))
   {
       cout<<"success"<<endl;
   }
```

compilation error:

```
 error: conversion from ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘testAttribute_map {aka std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >}’ requested
```

Comment: `find` returns an iterator, not a container. Once you fix that you're also not checking the value correctly, if it is not equal to `attributes.end()` the value was found. If it is equal then the value was not found. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `if(testAttribute_map iter = attributes.find(fileName))`

There is no implicit conversion from `testAttribute_map` to `bool` as you request above.

You also need the correct type for `iter` and you need to check if it's equal to `attributes.end()`:

```
testAttribute_map::iterator iter = attributes.find(fileName);
if(iter != attributes.end())
{
    std::cout<<"success\n";
}
```

or simpler:

```
if(auto iter = attributes.find(fileName); iter != attributes.end())
{
    std::cout<<"success\n";
}
```